# Catch all route for angular2 final and router 3.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am looking to create a "catch all" route in Angular2.

My routes are declared as follows (urls simplified for example):

```
{ path: 'action', component: MyComponent },
{ path: 'action/:suid/:cuid/:sa', component: MyComponent },
```

So the following works (using HashLocationStrategy)

```
http://localhost:4020/#/action
http://localhost:4020/#/action/11/22/33
```

But I want to have all routes after **action** be caught by the MyComponent.  I have code in the NgOnInit for the component that looks for params and throws an error if there is not three verified parameters.

But there is a chance that people can get to this page with improperly formed urls because this is a public page used to verify a url from an email that gets sent to the user.

if I provide just one, two, or more than three parameters then the following error is thrown in the console and the component is not loaded so my error message is not displayed

> Cannot match any routes: 'action/1/2'

### Question

So how can I have all routes with http://localhost:4020/#/action and any amount of parameters or any other "stuff" routed back to this component so the error message can be displayed

Comment: You could probably use `action/**`, but you need to be prepared to grab the params manually from the path segments (not be extracted by name as they won't exist). Something like `route.url.subscribe(url => {})`, where `url` will be an array of `UrlSegment`, each with a `path` property, representing a different segment, e.g  `action`, `1`, `2`.